# IMAP search with a full string

Tags: imap

I am currently trying to search some email in my Inbox with a string like that "not working anymore" but the problem is that imap will return me the list of email containing the 3 words and not the string "not working anymore".

Any idea how to resolve this? I have no messages containing this string, but the IMAP returns me 2 results because of the problem explained above.

```
a1 SEARCH BODY "not working anymore" 
* SEARCH 4090 7752
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter/verify the server's result in your client code.

The longer answer is that IMAP servers used to do what you want, but as users wanted smarter fuzzier faster searching, servers started implementing it. For example, users wanted to find messages like this:

```
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo not working
anymore foo foo foo foo
```

The whitespace does not match your search term. Do you think the server should return that message?

The IMAP specification is silentish on the issue. As I read it, if a message contains the exact string, that specification says the message must match the search, but if the message doesn't, then... well, then server and client should act to satisfy the user and bring about world peace. This implies that the search result you get from the server contains all the messages you want, so filtering won't miss any results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But in the datasheet, it's write that the function search body <string> match the phrase with body. In fact it's not matching the phrase but matching all the words of the phrase. Then i suppose there is no way to match the emails with a regex to find the good email to load, right ?

Comment: IMAP does not support regex seaches.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to research a woard at a specific position ?

Comment: It's not. Read the specification: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4 The normal solution is to send a search command to eliminate most messages in teh server, then do postprocessing on the remaining candidates in the client.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer and surprised it doesn't have more upvotes. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @billynoah IMAP-related answers aren't upvoted. Perhaps usage is dropping off and little new code written.